# Slow inference times for Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I've been working with the Tensorflow Object Detection API - In my case, I'm attempting to detect vehicles in still images using the kitti-trained model (faster_rcnn_resnet101_kitti_2018_01_28) from the model zoo and I am using code modified from the object_detection_tutorial jupyter notebook included in the github repository .

I have included my modified code below but am finding the same results with the original notebook from github.

When running on a jupyter notebook server on an `Amazon AWS g3x4large (GPU)` instance with the deep learning AMI, it takes just shy of 4 seconds to process a single image.  The time for the inference function is 1.3-1.5 seconds (see code below) - which seems ABNORMALLY high for the reported inference times for the model (20ms).  While I don't expect to hit the reported mark, my times seem out of line and are impractical for my needs.  I'm looking at processing 1-million+ images at a time and can't afford 46 days of processing time.  Given that the model is used on video frame captures....I would think it should be possible to cut time per image to under 1 second, at least.

My questions are:

1) What explanations/solutions exist to reduce inference time?

2) Is 1.5 seconds to convert an image to a numpy (prior to processing) out-of-line?

3) If this is the best performance I can expect, how much increase in time could I hope to gain from reworking the model to batch process images?

Thanks for any help!

Code from python notebook:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile
import json
import collections
import os.path
import datetime

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")

# This is needed to display the images.
get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')

#Setup variables
PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'test_images'

MODEL_NAME = 'faster_rcnn_resnet101_kitti_2018_01_28'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'kitti_label_map.pbtxt')

NUM_CLASSES = 2

from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

def get_scores(
    boxes,
    classes,
    scores,
    category_index,
    min_score_thresh=.5
):

  import collections
  # Create a display string (and color) for every box location, group any boxes
  # that correspond to the same location.
  box_to_display_str_map = collections.defaultdict(list)

  for i in range(boxes.shape[0]):
    if scores is None or scores[i] > min_score_thresh:
      box = tuple(boxes[i].tolist())
      if scores is None:
        box_to_color_map[box] = groundtruth_box_visualization_color
      else:
        display_str = ''
        if classes[i] in category_index.keys():
          class_name = category_index[classes[i]]['name']
        else:
          class_name = 'N/A'
        display_str = str(class_name)
        if not display_str:
          display_str = '{}%'.format(int(100*scores[i]))
        else:
          display_str = '{}: {}%'.format(display_str, int(100*scores[i]))
        box_to_display_str_map[i].append(display_str)

  return box_to_display_str_map

def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
  (im_width, im_height) = image.size
  return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
      (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

def run_inference_for_single_image(image, graph):
  with graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      # Get handles to input and output tensors
      ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
      all_tensor_names = {output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
      tensor_dict = {}
      for key in [
          'num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores',
          'detection_classes', 'detection_masks'
      ]:
        tensor_name = key + ':0'
        if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
          tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(
              tensor_name)
      if 'detection_masks' in tensor_dict:
        # The following processing is only for single image
        detection_boxes = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_boxes'], [0])
        detection_masks = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_masks'], [0])
        # Reframe is required to translate mask from box coordinates to image coordinates and fit the image size.
        real_num_detection = tf.cast(tensor_dict['num_detections'][0], tf.int32)
        detection_boxes = tf.slice(detection_boxes, [0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1])
        detection_masks = tf.slice(detection_masks, [0, 0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1, -1])
        detection_masks_reframed = utils_ops.reframe_box_masks_to_image_masks(
            detection_masks, detection_boxes, image.shape[0], image.shape[1])
        detection_masks_reframed = tf.cast(
            tf.greater(detection_masks_reframed, 0.5), tf.uint8)
        # Follow the convention by adding back the batch dimension
        tensor_dict['detection_masks'] = tf.expand_dims(
            detection_masks_reframed, 0)
      image_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

      # Run inference
      output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict,
                             feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image, 0)})

      # all outputs are float32 numpy arrays, so convert types as appropriate
      output_dict['num_detections'] = int(output_dict['num_detections'][0])
      output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict[
          'detection_classes'][0].astype(np.uint8)
      output_dict['detection_boxes'] = output_dict['detection_boxes'][0]
      output_dict['detection_scores'] = output_dict['detection_scores'][0]
      if 'detection_masks' in output_dict:
        output_dict['detection_masks'] = output_dict['detection_masks'][0]
  return output_dict

#get list of paths
exten='.jpg'
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS=[]

for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR):
    for name in files:
        if name.lower().endswith(exten):
            #print(os.path.join(dirpath,name))
            TEST_IMAGE_PATHS.append(os.path.join(dirpath,name))
print((len(TEST_IMAGE_PATHS), 'Images To Process'))

#load model graph for inference
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

#setup class labeling parameters    
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

#placeholder for timings
myTimings=[]

myX = 1
myResults = collections.defaultdict(list)
for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
  if os.path.exists(image_path):  
    print(myX,"--------------------------------------",datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now()))
    print(myX,"Image:", image_path)
    myTimings.append((myX,"Image", image_path))
    print(myX,"Open:",datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now()))
    myTimings.append((myX,"Open",datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now()).__str__()))
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
    # result image with boxes and labels on it.
    print(myX,"Numpy:",datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now()))
    myTimings.append((myX,"Numpy",datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now()).__str__()))
    image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
    # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    print(myX,"Expand:",datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now()))
    myTimings.append((myX,"Expand",datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now()).__str__()))
    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
    # Actual detection.
    print(myX,"Detect:",datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now()))
    myTimings.append((myX,"Detect",datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now()).__str__()))
    output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)
    # Visualization of the results of a detection.
    print(myX,"Export:",datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now()))
    myTimings.append((myX,"Export",datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now()).__str__()))
    op=get_scores(
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      min_score_thresh=.2)
    myResults[image_path].append(op)  
    print(myX,"Done:", datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now()))
    myTimings.append((myX,"Done", datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now()).__str__()))
    myX= myX + 1

#save results    
with open((OUTPUTS_BASENAME+'_Results.json'), 'w') as fout:
    json.dump(myResults, fout)
with open((OUTPUTS_BASENAME+'_Timings.json'), 'w') as fout:
    json.dump(myTimings, fout)
```

Example Of Timings:

```
[1, "Image", "test_images/DE4T_11Jan2018/MFDC4612.JPG"]
[1, "Open", "19:20:08.029423"]
[1, "Numpy", "19:20:08.052679"]
[1, "Expand", "19:20:09.977166"]
[1, "Detect", "19:20:09.977250"]
[1, "Export", "19:23:13.902443"]
[1, "Done", "19:23:13.903012"]
[2, "Image", "test_images/DE4T_11Jan2018/MFDC4616.JPG"]
[2, "Open", "19:23:13.903885"]
[2, "Numpy", "19:23:13.906320"]
[2, "Expand", "19:23:15.756308"]
[2, "Detect", "19:23:15.756597"]
[2, "Export", "19:23:17.153233"]
[2, "Done", "19:23:17.153699"]
[3, "Image", "test_images/DE4T_11Jan2018/MFDC4681.JPG"]
[3, "Open", "19:23:17.154510"]
[3, "Numpy", "19:23:17.156576"]
[3, "Expand", "19:23:19.012935"]
[3, "Detect", "19:23:19.013013"]
[3, "Export", "19:23:20.323839"]
[3, "Done", "19:23:20.324307"]
[4, "Image", "test_images/DE4T_11Jan2018/MFDC4697.JPG"]
[4, "Open", "19:23:20.324791"]
[4, "Numpy", "19:23:20.327136"]
[4, "Expand", "19:23:22.175578"]
[4, "Detect", "19:23:22.175658"]
[4, "Export", "19:23:23.472040"]
[4, "Done", "19:23:23.472297"]
```

Comment: In my case I did preload the sessions and graphs but I still am not able to get to the fullest. Can you please guide me through what else did you do @KLH ?

Answer (score 1):

1) What you can do is load the video directly instead of images, then change "run_inference_for_single_image()" to create the session once and load the images/video in it (re-creating the graph is very slow). Furthermore, you can edit the pipeline config file to reduce the number of proposals, which will directly speedup inference. Note you have to re-export the graph afterwards (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/exporting_models.md). Batch also helps (though I am sorry, I forgot by how much) and finally, you can employ multiprocessing to offload CPU specific operations (drawing bounding boxes, loading data) to utilize the GPU better.

2) Is 1.5 seconds to convert an image to a numpy (prior to processing) out-of-line <- yes, that is insanely slow and there is plenty of room for improvement.

3) While I don't know the exact gpu at AWS (k80?), you should be able to get over 10fps on a geforce 1080TI with all fixes, which is in line with the 79ms time they reported (where did you get 20ms for faster-rcnn_resnet_101?? )

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I may have been misleading, I'm using all still images and not video.

Comment: You are right, I missed the fact that I had to reload the graph for each single inference.  I believe I have rewrote my code so I could capture just the inference and hopefully not the loading of the graph.  The following line takes approximately 1.5 seconds to run on the AWS g3X4large instance.  Unless I'm missing something, the graph has already been loaded at this point.

I've realized the 1.8 seconds to convert an image to numpy also includes loading from file as well as a reshape......I'm assuming that is what is accounting for the time.

Comment: I also messed up with the 20ms time...got the numbers mixed up in my head...you are correct in that the reported time is 79ms.  However, I'm a long ways from that.

Comment: Maybe load the images into memory first and measure batches of detections? run_inference_for_single_image(image, graph):
Try fiddling with
`` with graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:``
and see if the double with slows down the code

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [OpenVINO](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_overview.html) for better performance of the inference. It optimizes the inference time by e.g. graph pruning and fusing some operations. OpenVINO is optimized for Intel hardware but it should work with any CPU (even with Cloud).

[Here](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_performance_benchmarks_openvino.html#faster-rcnn-resnet50-coco-tf-600x1024) are some performance benchmarks for the Faster RCNN Resnet model and various  CPUs.

It's rather straightforward to convert the Tensorflow model to OpenVINO unless you have fancy custom layers. The full tutorial on how to do it can be found [here](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks/tree/main/notebooks/101-tensorflow-to-openvino). Some snippets below.

**Install OpenVINO**

The easiest way to do it is using PIP. Alternatively, you can use [this tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/openvino-toolkit/download.html) to find the best way in your case.

```
pip install openvino-dev[tensorflow2]
```

**Use Model Optimizer to convert SavedModel model**

The Model Optimizer is a command-line tool that comes from OpenVINO Development Package. It converts the Tensorflow model to IR, which is a default format for OpenVINO. You can also try the precision of FP16, which should give you better performance without a significant accuracy drop (just change data_type). Run in the command line:

```
mo --saved_model_dir "model" --input_shape "[1, 3, 224, 224]" --data_type FP32 --output_dir "model_ir"
```

**Run the inference**

The converted model can be loaded by the runtime and compiled for a specific device e.g. CPU or GPU (integrated into your CPU like Intel HD Graphics). If you don't know what is the best choice for you, just use AUTO.

```
# Load the network
ie = Core()
model_ir = ie.read_model(model="model_ir/model.xml")
compiled_model_ir = ie.compile_model(model=model_ir, device_name="CPU")

# Get output layer
output_layer_ir = compiled_model_ir.output(0)

# Run inference on the input image
result = compiled_model_ir([input_image])[output_layer_ir]
```

There is even [OpenVINO Model Server][5] which is very similar to Tensorflow Serving.

Disclaimer: I work on OpenVINO.